# android gradle: plugin id java-library not found

Tags: java, android, gradle, gradle-plugin

The following works fine for a war project:

```
configure([project(':foo'), project(':bar')]) {
    apply plugin: 'java-library'
        ....
}
```

But for android,

```
plugin id 'java-library' not found
```

android root project build.gradle

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:2.3.3'
    }
}

configure([project(':foo'), project(':bar')]) {
        apply plugin: 'java-library'
            ....
}
```

subproject foo and bar: are java libraries.  Is the plugin disabled by android?

Answer (score 0):

Found out the gradle version with android studio is 3.3. After upgraded to 4.0, works.

Comment: consider deleting the question.

Comment: Tried to delete it, but got a warning that my account might be blocked in the future. :)